# localhost not working in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, server-configuration

I am unable to connect to localhost after the installation of the sql server 2005. however i am able to connect using my system name.

Is there a way i will be able to connect using localhost by making few changes??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use "`.`" (DOT) instead of localhost and you should be able to connect.

Comment: i have tried that too. No luck. Is there anything i did wrong while installing.

Comment: Also is there a way i can host two servers on my machine??

Comment: @Karthik - Why do you need two servers on your system. You will need two instances of databases in one server thats all if I am not wrong.

Comment: A network related or instance specific error occured i.e basically its not able to find the localhost service

Comment: @Karthik - you can host more than one database in your server anyway. Just use Attach functionality from management studio. Also for localhost to work, can you run `net start mssqlserver` in your command prompt and then try?

Comment: No luck yet. I am uninstalling my sql server and installing it again.